# Need to replace a comma with a pipe for csv export in java

Tags: java, csv, model-view-controller, controller

i need to export a csv file in txt; i wanna use a pipe for separate fields.
My code is something like
String[] x = {its1, its2, its3, its4, its5 };

i need:  {its1| its2| its3| its4| its5 }

ps. i'm in the controller of course.

```
@Controller

public class CSVFileDownloadController 
{ @RequestMapping(value ="/downloadCSV")   
 public void downloadCSV(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
 
        String csvFileName = "books.csv";
 
        response.setContentType("text/csv");
 
        // creates mock data
        String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
        String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"",
                csvFileName);
        response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
 
       
        List<Book> listBooks = Arrays.asList(); 
 
        // uses the Super CSV API to generate CSV data from the model data
        ICsvBeanWriter csvWriter = new CsvBeanWriter(response.getWriter(),
                CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);
 
        String[] header = { "Title", "Description", "Author", "Publisher",
                "isbn", "PublishedDate", "Price" };
 
        csvWriter.writeHeader(header);
 
        for (Book aBook : listBooks) {
            csvWriter.write(aBook, header);
        }
 
        csvWriter.close();
    }
}
```

Solved thanks @M.Deinum

Comment: "i need" you can't have that, because it looks like you want Java code like that, but it's not valid Java. Do you mean that you want to render it as `its1| its2| ` etc when you print it to the file?

Comment: Please show your controller.

Comment: yes, in text files that comes out

Comment: @kirinya added on the main question

Comment: Don't use `CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE` but construct your own using the `Builder`.

Comment: In your case, you need to check the used API for the possibility of a custom delimiter. https://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/apidocs/org/supercsv/prefs/CsvPreference.html might help.

Answer (score 0):

You could [`join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) the array:

```java
String result = String.join("|", x);
```

Comment: (But of course, that's not **c**sv).

Comment: @AndyTurner I thought **csv** stands for **C**haracter **S**eparated **V**alues

Comment: @BdR no, [comma-separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). [DSV (delimiter-separated values)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter-separated_values) is the (/a) more general term.

Comment: @AndyTurner that's a good point, thanks. Edited my answer to use a better term.